# Long distance file transmison

Tags: video, streaming-video, streaming, data-transfer

I want to send video files (approximately 70 MB) over a distance of 200 meters outdoors. I have some experience in using Raspberry pi and a lot of experience in Python and Java. I need some advice on which parts to use and how.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello and welcome. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-range_Wi-Fi  I think to remember about an answer around here pointing to some specific directional wifi setup, I just cannot find it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jacobsalmela.com](http://jacobsalmela.com/get-lakesh-wifi-cabin-making-antenna/) reports wifi reception with a range of 700m(!) using a cantenna. He used a fairly standard bag of tools plus a suitable can, a USB adapter with a removable antenna, cabling and an adapter.

Basic outline:

- Cut a 31mm length of 12 gauge copper wire
- Open the (cleaned) can at one end only
- Mount the copper wire and antenna cable connector to the can per below diagram
- Connect the cantenna to the USB WiFi adapter

[image: Diagram of antenna placement]

Comment: To add onto @goobering's answer with the can/copper wire, here is a WIFI adapter for the pi with a removable antenna if you wish to follow his answer; http://www.buyraspberrypi.com.au/shop/auspi-wireless-adaptor-802-11-bgn-wifi-for-raspberry-pi/

Comment: For maximum distance you will want some power, and a good Yagi antenna like this one:  http://www.ebay.com/itm/High-Gain-Long-Range-Yagi-18dBi-16dBi-2-4-GHz-WiFi-Antenna-Booster-Directional-/331809920627