# How can make a wireless connection between two Raspberry Pi in distance of 500 meters?

Tags: wifi, wireless, wireless-adapter

I should make a wireless mesh network on my project using Raspberry Pi. Those nodes are in distance in 500 meters range.

How can I make nodes(Raspberry Pi + sensors) to make right wireless connection? I mean using what kind of wireless standard? what kind of antenna or Wi-Fi dongle?

Comment: related: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/44094/19949

Comment: Use a dongle that allows external antennas to be connected.  Yagi antennas are very affordable and work well.  Something like this:  http://www.ebay.com/itm/High-Gain-Long-Range-Yagi-18dBi-16dBi-2-4-GHz-WiFi-Antenna-Booster-Directional-/331809920627